# How sampling and KL loss work in Variational Autoencoders?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoders, keras, generative-models

I am trying to learn about Variational Autoencoders and found this very [informative blog about vae's](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-variational-autoencoders-1bfe67eb5daf). I understood most part of vae's but cant understand how sampling and KL loss work in a vae.

This is the code which confuses me

```
def sampler(mean, log_stddev):
    # we sample from the standard normal a matrix of batch_size * latent_size (taking into account minibatches)
    std_norm = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(mean)[0], latent_size), mean=0, stddev=1)
    # sampling from Z~N(μ, σ^2) is the same as sampling from μ + σX, X~N(0,1)
    return mean + K.exp(log_stddev) * std_norm

latent_vector = Lambda(sampler)([mean, log_stddev])
# pass latent_vector as input to decoder layers
```

Can you give an intuitive explanaition of what is happeing in `sampler` and `Lambda` functions? Why vae needs KL loss?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05908 is a thorough explanation of the background behind VAEs

Answer (score 6):

The `sampler` function implements the reparameterization trick, it takes in the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and outputs a sample $z$ from the corresponding Gaussian, it follows $z=\mu + \sigma\epsilon$ and is differentiable wrt $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

`Lambda` is just a layer in Keras that allows you to customize a layer by passing in a function as parameter, so `Lambda(sampler)` instantiates a layer of the `sampler` function since there's no built-in sampler layer in Keras.

The KL divergence term is as part of the loss function in VAE definition.